# Groupplanning/seating problem

Tags: algorithms

First of; this is my first computer science problem, so bear with me. That said:

I'm trying to create a planning application for my summer camp (sailing school) with the goal to put everyone with different people every day (when possible).

**Variables** *defaults*

- Group size: 4 (max. people per boat)
- Total people: 20
- Days: 5

**Day 1**

```
| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| 1       | 5       | 9       | 13      | 17      |
| 2       | 6       | 10      | 14      | 18      |
| 3       | 7       | 11      | 15      | 19      |
| 4       | 8       | 12      | 16      | 20      |
```

**Goal**

Calculate an optimized roster for each of the remaining days

```
| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| ?       | ?       | ?       | ?       | ?       |
| ?       | ?       | ?       | ?       | ?       |
| ?       | ?       | ?       | ?       | ?       |
| ?       | ?       | ?       | ?       | ?       |
```

1. People need to be spread over the boats. (If there are 17 people, no group can be size 1)
2. Where everyone is with a completely new group of people everyday, if possible.
3. Where everyone is in a different group, when possible.

**What i've done**

I made a script that does the following (without knowledge of any algoritm):

```
for (everyday) :
    reset table & people
    while (people > 0) :
        order people by: 
            - currently placed people who've been in the same group
        pick the one with the most matches
        order groups by: 
            - skip full groups
            - number of people from previous groups (-10 per person)
            - has been in this group (-1 per group)
            - current groupsize (-1 per person in group)
        put the one in the highest scoring group
```

I got pretty good results with using this, but with some fiddling and trying some other rules I found that shuffling the people before the ordering of said people who give me sometimes better/worse results. So...

- I was wondering if my approach is any good?
- Is this a NP-complete or NP-hard problem or neither? Is it dependant on the day the roster is made?
- Is it even possible to eliminate the randomness and create an algoritm which always returns the best result?
- Do you know of some similar problems/examples where I can learn from? I found the [list of NP-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems), but I don't know which one really compares to my case.

Cheers,
Ties

Comment: Look up *block designs*.

Comment: If you want a very simple (but not optimal) solution, random assignments are often pretty good.

Comment: I'm now looking into combinatronics and hypergraphs. The block designs we're very usefull to understand what I'm doing now, and improve the logic. Good to hear that it's not weird to use random functions in the logic, I'll keep using it untill I find a better solution or decide the logic is good enough and the randomised results are (potentially) significantly better.